# How do I override the layout for a custom extension in RefineryCMS?

Tags: ruby, refinerycms, refinery

I generated an extension for RefineryCMS, following the instructions in the Refinery Guide for 'Generate an Extension to Use Your MVCs'. I now need to alter the layout, but where is it? I cannot find any documentation that will tell me where I might overwrite it from.

Comment: it's been 21 days - no one has a clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late.

If I well undestood your issue, I will advise you to add your custom `layout` inside `app/views/layout/my_custom_layout.html.erb`.

Then I render it as follow in your extension view:

`<%= render '/layout/my_custom_layout' %>`

Hope It will help someone.